# Swift/MySql/PHP - "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." error

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, xcode

I am getting this error when I try to load mysql data into my swift program. I am trying to get the output in console before I put it in my SwiftUI. When I debug with breakpoint, I can see data loaded into the variable, but it just can't be read by Swift. Watched numerous videos if I find any fix, but no luck.

Error : **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

Getting error at this line:
`let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)`

Any help greatly appreciate as it has been almost a week since I stuck here. Thank you.

here is my complete code.

- Post.swift Struct:

```
import Foundation

struct Post: Codable {
    var Name: String!
    var City: String!
}
```

- JsonViewController.swift Class:

```
import UIKit

class JsonViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        fetchPostData { (posts) in
            for post in posts {
                print(post.Name!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchPostData(completionHandler: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://localhost/service.php")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                
                let postsData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
                
                completionHandler(postsData)
            }
            catch {
                let error = error
                
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                
            }
            
        }
        task.resume()
    }

}
```

Output in web browser - from service.php:

```
[{"Name":"John","City":"Sydney"}]
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to have anything to do with php

Comment: Actually, I have just figured out an issue with my service.php file, that had few html tags that was causing an issue. Working fine after cleaning the file. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the data is loaded correctly in JSON format in web browser, It will not parse correctly in Swift if your service.php file has any HTML tags etc before and after php tags. Very silly mistake, but hope that helps others.